# removing pulseaudio, moving to jack

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, jack

I have installed jack because I want to use the LADSPA plugins available, in jackrack, for realtime audio processing. (I couldn't find any way to use them with pulseaudio)

After much effort, I managed to get pulseaudio to work at the same time by getting to act as a source/sink under jack after installing pulseaudio-module-jack. Still, as a solution, it is messy.  I am wondering if I can remove pulseaudio. Will all common applications be able to use jack instead of pulseaudio? How much reconfiguring will there be?  What are the tricks involved in making it work?

Any tips will be gratefully received.

Comment: Nope. Jack is for specific apps. You cant use jack for app like Rhythmbox.

Comment: It appears your question has a full (and satisfying) answer now: http://askubuntu.com/questions/572120/how-to-use-jack-and-pulseaudio-alsa-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-audio-device