# Video doesn't run when Jack Audio Connection Kit is on

Tags: sound, jack

As soon as I start JACK I can't watch any videos on google chrome. The videos are just buffering and directly when I turn JACK off JACK they start playing.

Answer (score 2):

The answer may be here
[How to use JACK and Pulseaudio/ALSA at the same time on the same audio device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572120/how-to-use-jack-and-pulseaudio-alsa-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-audio-device)

It looks like this software: "pulseaudio-module-jack" is needed.  Chrome uses pulseaudio so jack needs to know how to work with pulseaudio.

Answer (score 1):

install package for pulseaudio-jack connection as 1st answer

If using Qjackctl to start JACK, check D-Bus settings are enabled for audio card to switch from Pulseaudio to JACK

If JACK cannot use D-Bus:  `pacmd suspend true` will allow JACK to start and claim use of ALSA device(s)

Videos in web browser will not play if still trying to connect to ALSA device in Pulseaudio
Web browser needs audio re-directed to Pulseaudio JACK Sink for video to play

Use `pavucontrol -t 1` to change Playback stream
Click drop-down menu to change from ALSA output device to Pulseaudio Sink.
Video should start to play as soon as playback device is changed

pavucontrol saves change of playback stream settings and should work correctly for similar audio streams from same source once set correctly first time

Comment: After trying many things, this simple change in pauvcontrol solved it for me.