# Why can't I use sound simultaneously in Bitwig and another program? Is Jack the problem?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I've recently installed [Bitwig](https://www.bitwig.com) to make some music. It installed fine, but it initially didn't produce any sound through my speakers. It also gave an error saying that it couldn't find Jack (or something similar, I don't exactly remember what it said). I then found [this topic](https://answers.bitwig.com/questions/1134/how-do-i-correctly-setup-audio-under-linux) in which it was suggested to run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsamixergui patchage jackd2   jackd2-firewire qjackctl a2jmidid gmidimonitor
```

After that Bitwig now works like a charm.

The only pretty annoying side effect, is that when I've got Bitwig open no other application can produce sound. So I can't play a video through vlc or watch a youtube video. Especially not being able to play youtube is annoying since I'm watching a lot of instructions video's to learn how to make music using Bitwig.

I suppose the problem has something to do with `jack` and `alsa`, but I've got no clue how I would start debugging or fixing this.

Does anybody know what I can do to be able to play sound through both Bitwig and the browser? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Jack will take over your sound card, making it unavailable for PulseAudio. There are various workarounds listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572120/how-to-use-jack-and-pulseaudio-alsa-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-audio-device).