# How to use a ffado firewire audio interface in qjackctl?

Tags: drivers, sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, firewire

I try to use my `Focusrite Saffire PRO 24` firewire audio interface with `Kubuntu 18.10` on my `Dell LATITUDE E6510` Laptop.

if i plug it in in a clean system it gets detected and i can have my system sounds (firefox media or other media players) coming out from it. yeah! ;-)

but after some time - seconds up to minutes - seems random - the connection crashes:

```
dmesg
...
[ 2273.445706] firewire_ohci 0000:04:00.4: DMA context IT0 has stopped, error code: evt_timeout
[ 2273.445722] firewire_ohci 0000:04:00.4: DMA context IR0 has stopped, error code: evt_descriptor_read
```

i have searched up and down the net a little -
one recommendation is to use a special driver `the ffado project` and jack.

i have setup jack with pulseaudio [as in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/777136/207905). That is working fine with the default system audio out.

i also have installed ffado-mixer via apt.
the FFADO Mixer Application is working nicely and i can configure my card as needed (internal routing and levels..)

but i can't get jack configured to use the alternative firewire driver (ffado) -
after some more research and experiments i [found](https://sourceforge.net/p/ffado/mailman/message/35041532/) that newer kernels include `snd_dice` 
- a build in driver for the `dice` based cards that work together with alsa.
so now i know why it works 'out of the box' - that is cool!
but as i written above - this has stability issues in my setup. (most likely the used firewire chip in my laptop - a `Ricoh Co Ltd - R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller` plays a crucial rule in this.. as fare as all the info i found TI chipsets should work much better)

so my goal is to go on with testing the alternative ffado driver:

for this i have `blacklisted snd_dice`:

```
stefan@stefan-Latitude-E6510:~$ sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire-local.conf
stefan@stefan-Latitude-E6510:~$ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire-local.conf
stefan@stefan-Latitude-E6510:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire-local.conf
blacklist snd_dice

stefan@stefan-Latitude-E6510:~$
```

then restarted the system..
now if i check with `lsmod | grep snd_dice` i don't see snd_dice - so the blacklisting seems to work.

a quick test with `ffado-mixer` is working correctly.
also the `ffado-test ListDevices` command finds the card:

```
$ ffado-test ListDevices
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
-----------------------------------------------
FFADO test and diagnostic utility
Part of the FFADO project -- www.ffado.org
Version: 2.4.1
(C) 2008, Daniel Wagner, Pieter Palmers
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
-----------------------------------------------

=== 1394 PORT 0 ===
  Node id  GUID                  VendorId     ModelId   Vendor - Model
   0       0x00130e0401c031e3  0x0000130E  0x00000007   Focusrite - SAFFIRE_PRO_24
no message buffer overruns
```

but the problem persists:
i can't get jack to see the card:
[image: qjackctl setup dialog - missing device]

have i missed something here?

i thought that the card should pop up in this list - especially if i have blacklisted the other driver..

I hope some of you have a idea / tips how to go on from here :-)

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: sadly not.
and with my new laptop i have no easy accessible firewire interface anymore :-(

Comment: I never managed to get qjackctl working but running `jackd -d firewire ...` works just fine.

Comment: Oh, and I'm using the USB-C port on _my_ new laptop and it works without any problems :)