# Starting DAW kills audio in other apps

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio

Starting Reaper stops audio in Spotify and also stops Youtube.  Closing Reaper resolves the issue.  I'd like to run them all.  I'm new to Ubuntu and still trying to understand how everything works.  Thank you

Comment: Reaper is not in the Ubuntu repositories and is therefore not supported.

Comment: When you I start Ardour5  I also start Jack, therefore Pulse gets suspended until I stop Ardour5 again. If you want to use it alongside there is already an answer to your question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/572120/how-to-use-jack-and-pulseaudio-alsa-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-audio-device