# audio - how to output guitarix sound to built-in headphones

Tags: sound, speakers, audio-jack

I have installed [JACK](https://jackaudio.org/) as well as [guitarix](http://guitarix.org/) and my ultimate goal is to plug in my guitar to play along with some backing tracks, for example from youtube.

**System Information**: I am running a full Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS system (no virtual box)

I am using the [Apogee Jam+](https://apogeedigital.com/products/jam) as interface and so far I can get the sound from guitarix outputted to my headphones, as long as these are connected to the Jam+ interface. As I cannot get any sound from my computer (e.g. from Youtube) outputted into the headphones connected to the Jam+, I wanted to output the sounds from guitarix to the headphones connected to the computer (and not to the Jam+)

My QJackctl connection looks like so (note the difference between my connection and the one shown [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-set-up-and-use-guitarix-on-linux/), though I don't think this makes such a great difference:

[image]

Below is a screenshot of the basic parameters:

[image]

And on the advanced parameters it is where I have to choose the output device, which for both Input and Output are `hw:Plus (JAM Plus hw:1)`

[image]

In order to get the sound outputted to the headphones when connected to the computer, I pretty much change all the possible values on Output device (screenshot above). Though I did not restart guitarix - I only stopped and started the JACK after changing the output device.

Finally, even though I don't think it might be related, below is a screenshot of the sound settings of my Ubuntu system itself

[image]

Has anyone successfully outputted the sound from guitarix into the headphones when connected to the computer (and not to the audio interface)?

Comment: thanks for the comment, I agree I should have added this information before hand, have edited the question

Comment: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572120/how-to-use-jack-and-pulseaudio-alsa-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-audio-device) addresses my issue

Comment: It does yes, as stated in my previous comment

Comment: The 'Does this answer...` is automatically injected when someone finds a prior solution and moves to close the question as a duplicate. This is a housekeeping move to avoid duplicate issues in the questionbase and does not reflect on you or your groovyness.