# guitar & browser audio at same time

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I'm using this guide:
https://medium.com/@margitai.i/how-to-set-up-an-open-source-guitar-rig-on-linux-5a5cce7bd916
to try and play bass and listen to play along with youtube videos. When the jack server is running, the ALSA system sounds are down.
When I look at the qjackctl graph in my system, I don't see the PulseAudio Jack source or sink windows like the tutorial has in their screenshot. Looks like I need to run all system sounds using jack, but that is not an option in the ubuntu audio settings.

How do I set this up properly, or why am I missing the PulseAudio Jack sink and source in my qjackctl graph windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JACK and Pulseaudio/ALSA at the same time on the same audio device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572120/how-to-use-jack-and-pulseaudio-alsa-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-audio-device)

Comment: I had the same problem - no PulseAudio JACK sink/source in QjackCtl... and once I got that working, I still couldn't hear YouTube with JACK running. The solution, in Ubuntu Studio, which uses KDE desktop: in QjackCtl-Setup-Misc tab, tick Enable JACK D-Bus interface. Apply the change. Now, when I start JACK, I have those sink/source entries, but still can't hear videos through JACK. Next: in my Ubuntu system's Settings-Audio, I can see that my interface is selected. If I tick the box next to "JACK sink (PulseAudio JACK Sink)," I can then hear both the video and my guitar through the interface.

Comment: I have enabled the Jack-D-Bus Interface; still do not see sink and source windows in the graph.

Comment: @mook765 I'm using the 'execute script after startup' pacmd set-default-sink jack_out and trying pactl set-default-sink jack_out, neither is working.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio came pre-configured with all this stuff, so I can't be of much more help, except to say that I leave all of those options under Scripting blank (i.e. execute script after startup) and only make the changes in my above comment. Good luck!

Comment: @hmcooky Please add relevant information via edit to your question instead of posting comments. What is your Ubuntu version and flavour? When you run the mentioned commands in a terminal instead of the execute script, do you get any error messages? If so, please provide them.